# Un deuxième couplet de la chanson « On se ressemble »

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson, figure-de-style

Voici encore un morceau de la chanson *On se ressemble* des Vieilles Valises que je ne comprends pas nettement.

> C'était un peu une princesse
>   J'étais ni prince, ni charmant
>   Elle avait un palais trois pièces
>   duquel elle me dit "VA T'EN !"

Pouvez-vous m’indiquer quelle est la fonction de « pièce » ici, et m’expliquer comment comprendre la troisième ligne ?

Je sais qu’on peut parfois remplacer morceau et partie par pièce, et que l’on parle de « pièces d’argent ». Je pense même avoir entendu quelqu’un dire *pièce*, soit au lieu de *dortoir*, soit pour désigner l’ensemble de lits qui s’y trouvaient. Ces deux sens n’ont pas vraiment de convenance avec les paroles de la chanson.

Le Wiktionnaire a dédié une très grande page à ce mot. Je crains pourtant que je ne comprendrais pas cette partie de la chanson, même si je lisais mûrement tout ce qu’on y a écrit. Il est pensable que le parolier fait allusion à un conte que je ne connais pas.

En outre, la troisième ligne a l’air tordue. Peut-être les paroles que j’ai trouvées en ligne sont fausses, mais j’en doute fort.

Comment: Je suis désolé de ne pas avoir utilisé les guillemets français partout, et de ne pas avoir encastré les paroles comme il faut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans ce contexte, pièce signifie « élément d'habitation dans un logement », par exemple :
une chambre, un salon, une salle à manger sont des pièces.

> Elle avait un palais trois pièces

Signifie, qu'elle avait un petit appartement (un salon et deux chambres par exemple), le mot palais est ici employé de façon ironique.

Comment: J’ai oublié de vous poser une petite question : Qu’est-ce qui *duquel* veut dire ici ? Est-ce que la femme ladite se trouve dans son « palais » quand elle dit « va t’en » ?

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin: « duquel » est la forme élidée de « de lequel ». « Lequel » représente le palais. On pourrait dire « Depuis lequel » ou « depuis son palais, elle me dit "va-t-en" (de mon palais) ».